# Withdraw All Eth From The Contract

Tags: solidity

I want to write a function that would withdraw all the Ether from the contract:

```
function withdraw() {
   adminAddress.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

1. Should I consider here subtracting the (gas-cost * gas-price) from the address(this).balance, or is it going to get paid from the one's address, who called the function?
2. If I have to calculate (gas-cost * gas-price), how could I do it using pure Solidity?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since gas usage is a factor outside the contract, it cannot be calculated within the contract. The account that called the function (EOA) pays for gas. It is not paid by the contract.